# ¿Por qué tengo que esperar 24 horas para dar una recompensa por respuesta ejemplar?

Tags: soporte, recompensas

Hoy he añadido una recompensa en la pregunta [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un inner y un outer join?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-un-inner-y-un-outer-join).

El tipo de recompensa que he elegido es:

> Una o más de las respuetas son ejemplares y valen una recompensa adicional.

Ya que me ha sido de mucha ayuda [esta fantástica respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/40/7242) y quería darle un pequeño extra.

Lo curioso es que no me deja asignarle la recompensa a la respuesta hasta pasadas las 24 horas. ¿Por qué?

Entiendo que para los otros tipos de recompensa es necesario esperarse, ya que se busca más atención y así varios usuarios pueden dar otras respuestas y esperar a la de más calidad o mejor uso, pero en este caso en el que ya se escoge para dárselo a una respuesta existente ¿por qué es necesario esperar este tiempo?

Comment: Puede que en esas 24 horas surja una nueva respuesta espectacular

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Pero este tipo de recompensa está pensado para dárselo a una respuesta ya realizada, no? Entiendo que *podría* haber una nueva respuesta pero mi objetivo inicial es dársela a esa respuesta (que creo que es la definición de esa recompensa)... No lo acabo de ver

Comment: El sistema trata de ser lo más imparcial posible. Entonces, no es justo otorgar el premio directamente en ese día. Esperar 24 horas es algo justo, como te digo puede que alguien brinde una respuesta mucho más completa que la que ya existe (no he visto eso aquí todavía pero en el sitio en inglés sí lo he vivido). Aún así, al final del tiempo mínimo, puedes otorgar el premio a quien tú prefieras.

Comment: Pero para eso están el resto de recompensas no? Hay para que salgan más respuestas (todas) por motivos distintos excepto este tipo que yo entendía que era para premiar una ya existente independientemente de lo que se genere a psoteriori

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea de la recompensa es que una pregunta reciba más atención y así recompensar a una respuesta. Esto se explica en [¿Qué es una recompensa? ¿Cómo puedo iniciar una?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) (énfasis mía):

> Si has formulado una buena pregunta, la has editado con actualizaciones sobre estado y progreso, y aun así no estás recibiendo respuestas, **puedes atraer atención hacia tu pregunta iniciando una recompensa**.
>
> Una recompensa **es un premio especial de reputación** concedido a una respuesta.

Hay que considerar que este concepto debe aplicar **a todas las preguntas**. Si hay preguntas que necesitan más atención, al iniciar una recompensa se llama la atención de usuarios que quieren ganar dicha recompensa, por ende debe haber un periodo de gracia para poder evaluar las respuestas publicadas antes de otorgar la recompensa.

Aplicando esta idea sobre preguntas que ya tienen una respuesta, puede suceder que la pregunta ya tenga una respuesta aceptada pero que para un usuario esa respuesta no sea la apropiada y quiera recibir otras respuestas. En este caso, puede iniciar una recompensar y posiblemente aparecerán más respuestas de buena calidad (para ganar la recompensa). Nuevamente, debe haber un periodo de gracia para revisar estas respuestas (si las hay) y luego aplicar la recompensa.

En tu caso particular, que es agradecer a un usuario por su respuesta, puedes iniciar una recompensa en la pregunta y **luego del periodo de gracia (1 día)** podrás brindar la recompensa a la respuesta que más te agrade. Si solo hay una respuesta o solo tienes en mente una respuesta, pues aplica la recompensa a ella. Sea cual sea tu caso particular para brindar la recompensa, todas siguen las mismas reglas y no hay excepciones para saltarlas.